# C++ - Pathfinding corner problems

Tags: c++, path-finding

So i'm trying to make characters walk around a tile map, using the following code. `tilePath` returns a vector of tiles in the path to their target, then their code makes them advance to the next tile in the vector. The problem is that when they get to a corner, they try to move around it too early and end up getting stuck on the wall.

[image]

The white squares are walkable tiles, the gray is a wall, and the red is a character. If the character gets to the corner walkable tile, it tries to move around the wall too soon, thus getting blocked by it. They usually end up making it around, but its very noticeable that they've gotten stuck on the wall for a bit.

```
std::vector<Tile*> TileMap::tilePath(Tile *p_start, Tile *p_end)
{
    std::vector<Tile*> path;
    std::vector<Tile*> open;
    std::map<uint64_t, Tile*> closed;

    p_start->previousTile = p_start;

    p_start->g = 0;
    p_start->h = 0;
    p_start->f = 0;

    float g, h, f, cost;

    Tile* current = p_start;
    Tile* previous = nullptr;
    while(current != p_end) {
        current->m_sprite.setColor(sf::Color(255,255,255,255));
        for(auto neighbor : getNeighbors(current))
        {
            if(neighbor == current) continue;
            if(!(neighbor->m_walkable)) continue;

            previous = current;

            if(tileTrace(current->previousTile, neighbor)) {
                cost = manhattan(current->previousTile, neighbor);
                g = current->previousTile->g + cost;
                h = manhattan(neighbor, p_end);
                f = g + h;
                previous = current->previousTile;
            } else {
                cost = ((current->m_coordinates.x != neighbor->m_coordinates.x) && (current->m_coordinates.y != neighbor->m_coordinates.y)) ? 1.4 : 1;
                g = current->g + cost;
                h = manhattan(neighbor, p_end);
                f = g + h;
            }

            if(std::find(open.begin(), open.end(), neighbor) != open.end() ||
               closed.find(neighbor->key()) != closed.end()) {
                if(neighbor->f > f) {
                    neighbor->f = f;
                    neighbor->g = g;
                    neighbor->h = h;
                    neighbor->previousTile = previous;
                }
            } else {
                neighbor->f = f;
                neighbor->g = g;
                neighbor->h = h;
                neighbor->previousTile = previous;
                for(auto i = open.begin(); i != open.end(); i++)
                {
                    if(neighbor->f < (*i)->f) {
                        open.insert(i, neighbor);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                open.push_back(neighbor);
            }
        }

        closed[current->key()] = current;
        if(open.size() == 0) {
            return std::vector<Tile*>();
        }
        current = open.front();
        open.erase(open.begin());
    }
    current = p_end;
    path.insert(path.begin(), current);
    while(current->previousTile != p_start)
    {
        current->m_sprite.setColor(sf::Color(255,0,0,255));
        path.insert(path.begin(), current->previousTile);
        current = current->previousTile;
    }

    return path;
}

bool TileMap::tileTrace(Tile* p_start, Tile* p_end)
{
    int sx = p_start->m_coordinates.x;
    int sy = p_start->m_coordinates.y;
    int ex = p_end->m_coordinates.x;
    int ey = p_end->m_coordinates.y;
    int dx = fabsf(ex - sx);
    int dy = fabsf(ey - sy);

    int _x = sx, _y = sy;
    int x_inc = (ex > sx) ? 1 : -1;
    int y_inc = (ey > sy) ? 1 : -1;
    int error = dx - dy;

    for(int n = dx + dy; n > 0; n--) {
        Tile& t = m_tiles[_y * m_width + _x];
        if(!(t.m_walkable)) return false;
        if(error < 0) {
            _y += y_inc;
            error += dx;
        } else {
            _x += x_inc;
            error -= dy;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

What can I do to make this a little smoother? I'd rather the characters not bounce off of the walls either.

Update:

I've added this to see if the character is moving towards or away from the tile it's "on". Granted it's more effective in getting the character around corners, but it sometimes gives a little strange movement.

```
sf::Vector2f d = start->m_position - p_object->m_position;
float dot = p_object->m_velocity.x * d.x + p_object->m_velocity.y * d.y;
if(dot > 0) {
    path.insert(path.begin(), start);
}
```

Comment: The easy way would be to track the middle of the player and the middle of the tile, and don't turn the corner until the middle of the player gets to the center of the tile (right now, it looks like you're trying to turn as soon as the middle of the player passes the blocking tile).

Comment: Somewhere in your code is code that detects the collision (`error`?)  Alter that code to move the remaining distance entirely in the unhindered axis instead of simply ignoring progress in the hindered axis.  This results in more normal cornering, they'll even slide out a touch from the corner.

Comment: @MooingDuck, hate to admit this, but someone actually helped me (a while ago, in a different project) with the `error` code that you're referring to, and I'm not 100% sure how to change it to make it work like you're suggesting. I had a ray trace that went from the center of one tile to the next, detecting wall collisions, but it often missed corners as well.

Comment: @EvanWard: I have now studied the `tileTrace` function and I deem it bizarre but it seems to work fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5fed927d4220684  However, it will only try the straightest path, if that's blocked, it returns `false`. (Actually, it picks a weird path from 0,0 to -1,-1...)

Comment: Since `tilePath` only deals with complete tiles, and has nothing dealing with offsets within a tile, I can guarantee the bug is not in this function.  The bug is in whatever code is detecting the collision and canceling the movement.

Comment: Simple solution, don't allow characters to change directions (to move to another tile) until they are completely on one tile. This was my solution to the exact same problem on a project 7-8 years ago. If I can find the source code, I'll convert this to an answer.